# Send activation code after registration

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, email

this is my simple registration. I want to send an email to the user's after submitting button in this registration form.How can i do that??Thanx in advance.
1. In the view i have made an simple registration form as u can see i have added some basic information.
2.In my controller i have added validations. And save them in database.
4.And model has simple insert query.

form_view.php

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td><td><?php echo form_input($name);?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_error('name');?></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td><td><?php echo form_input($email);?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_error('email');?></td>

    </tr>


<tr>
        <td>Phone</td><td><?php echo form_input($phone);?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_error('phone');?></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Address</td><td><?php echo form_input($address);?></td>
        <td><?php echo form_error('address');?></td>

    </tr>

       <tr>
           <td>Division</td><td><?php echo form_dropdown('division',$division,'Please Select');?></td>

    </tr>

          <td></td><td><?php echo form_submit($submit);?></td>

    </tr>


</table>
```

main.php

```
 <?php

    class main extends CI_Controller{
    public function viewForm(){

            $this->load->view('form_view');


        }

        public function insertData(){
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[address.name]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'Contact field', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[address.phone]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'Full Address', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[address.address]');
              $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|is_unique[address.email]');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
           $this->load->view('form_view');     
            }else{

            $sql="Select MAX(id) from address";// Auto Increment
            $query=  mysql_query($sql);
            $selectid=  mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $finalid=$selectid[0]+1;

            $data=array();
            $data['id']=$finalid;

            $data=array();
            $data['name']=$this->input->post('std_name');
            $data['phone']=$this->input->post('std_phone');
            $data['address']=$this->input->post('std_address');
            $data['division']=$this->input->post('division');
            $data['email']=$this->input->post('email');

            $this->load->model('main_model');
            $this->main_model->save_user($data);
            redirect('main/viewForm');
          }
        }
```

main_model.php

```
 <?php

    class main_model extends CI_Model{
        public function save_user($data){
        $this->db->insert('address',$data);

        }
    ?>

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider adding two columns on you user info table. Something like `varchar activation_code` & `tinyint activated`. On save user info generate activation code and send user a mail with that code within a link of your application url as well as save that code for that specific user with activated `false` value. On verify that code using that link change activated to `true`.
That will be my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start, I just want to point out that you should not have queries in your controller. That part must be in a model.

To send an email, you can use the codeigniter's library : 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html

Here's how you can use it in your case :

```
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
{
   $this->load->view('form_view');     
}
else
{
     $email = $this->input->post('email');

    //Your stuff before the redirect

    //If you have any particular smtp configuration (here, gmail)
    $config = Array(
         'protocol'  =>  'smtp',
         'smtp_host' =>  'smtp.gmail.com',
         'smtp_user' =>  'myemail@gmail.com',
         'smtp_pass' =>  'mypassword',
         'smtp_port' =>  '465',
         'charset' => 'utf-8',
         'wordwrap' => TRUE
     );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    $this->email->from('MyName@MySite.com', 'MyName');
    $this->email->to($email); 
    $this->email->subject('Mail subject');
    $msg = "Welcome to my website !";
    $this->email->message($msg);

    if($this->email->send())
    {     
        //Stuff if mail succeded
    }
    else 
    {
        //Stuff if mail failed
    }

    redirect('main/viewForm');

}
```

Comment: Thanx i am trying the above code and i will give you feedback